# Can't get a normal animation in Java(figure just appears in another place, doesn't slide)

Tags: java, swing, animation

I've got a problem here. The program below creates an animation ( a circle going from one point to another). The animation should start when you click the button.

The problem is that when I click the button, I cannot see the circle sliding. It just appears, after some time, in other place.

It's seems interesting to me(as a beginner), that if I do not use a button, and call the *moveIt()* method inside *go()*, I get a normal animation (I can see the circle sliding).

Can you give me, please, some suggestions on this problem ?

Thanks.

Here's the program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.*;

final public class MiniMiniMusicPlayer1 implements ActionListener
{

    JFrame frame;
    DrawPanel drawPanel;

    private int X = 7;
    private int Y = 7;



    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        new MiniMiniMusicPlayer1().go();
    }

    private void go()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Player");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

        JButton buttonStart = new JButton("Start animation");
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonStart);
        buttonStart.addActionListener(this);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
        moveIt();
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel
    {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(X, Y, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    private void moveIt()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            X++;
            Y++;
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            frame.repaint();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing and AWT work using an Event Dispatch thread. That thread is responsible for handling all events (running the event handlers, such as a button's `actionPerformed`) and repaint requests.

When you run your `moveIt` from `go`, it is ran by the *main* thread. It creates repaint requests, and the event dispatch thread, which runs concurrently with the main thread, dispatches them. Thus, you can see the animation.

But when you call `moveIt` from an event handler, it is ran by the event dispatch thread itself. Thus, the whole loop is performed, and all the repaint requests are queued, but the thread is busy and can't dispatch them until it's finished the loop.

When it is done with the loop, it dispatches the repaints (or rather, it dispatches just one, there is no need for it to repaint 100 times). The repaint is done given the final state of X and Y.

If you want to see animations, you should make sure you are not running them inside the EDT. You can use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) object for this, for example.

Remember never to run a long operation inside an event handler. It holds up the EDT and makes your GUI unresponsive. Never use `Thread.sleep()` in an event handler. If your long task is supposed to do something on a periodic basis, use a `Timer`. If it's supposed to do some big task like load from database, use `SwingWorker`.